# Cannot copy files but can copy folders to SMB share

Tags: finder, network, sharing, smb

I've set up my Raspberry Pi to share an external HDD as a samba share. My clients are macOS 11.6 and 11.5.

I've followed the Samba Wiki page on how to [configure samba to work better with Apple](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configure_Samba_to_Work_Better_with_Mac_OS_X).

I can see and connect to my share. I can delete files and folders. I can rename and move them. I can copy directories to the Samba share. The only thing I can't do is copy over individual files. When I do this, I get error 100093.

These are my Samba global settings

```
min protocol = SMB2
vfs objects = fruit streams_xattr
fruit:metadata = stream
fruit:model = MacSamba
fruit:veto_appledouble = no
fruit:posix_rename = yes
fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
```

Googling around I did find [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/q02ss3/files_app_osstatus_error_100093/) with a proposed fix that seems to have worked for others. I tried this, using the following Samba global settings

```
min protocol = SMB2
vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
fruit:nfs_aces = no
fruit:metadata = stream
fruit:model = MacSamba
fruit:veto_appledouble = no
fruit:posix_rename = yes
fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
```

Exact same behaviour and error.

Any idea what could be causing this?